# C++ Cast binary array to a class

Tags: c++, class, casting

How can I cast a binary array to a known class?

Essentially I have a byte array of data like so:

```
unsigned char * buff[sizeof(MyClass)];
```

I'm using `unsigned char` for each byte as I assume it is a length of 1 byte.

How can I cast this array to what I know the data represents? I have taken the data from memory of MyClass, and put it in this buffer - now I need to cast it back to `MyClass`.

I've seen `reinterpret_cast` but I'm not sure if it would apply here.

Comment: What you have is an array of character pointers. I doubt that's what you intended. And yes, you can use `reinterpret_cast`, but why do you want to do this in the first place?

Comment: @TaylorBrandstetter By an array of character pointers, I actually meant to have a pointer to an array of characters. How can I fix this?

Comment: unsigned char * buff; buff = new unsigned char[sizeof(MyClass)];

Comment: You don't need a pointer to an array, you just need an array. If you declare `unsigned char buff[sizeof(MyClass)];` and do `reinterpret_cast<MyClass *>(buff)`, `buff` will end up acting like an `unsigned char *`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unsigned char* buff[sizeof(MyClass)]` is an array of `unsigned char*`, which is likely to be `4` or `8` times bigger than what you're expecting. (32 and 64bit platforms respectively, although, there are architectures that have even different pointer sizes - nitpick protection)

To answer the casting part of the question, `reinterpret_cast<T*>(buff)` will handle the chunk as `T*`.

Comment: Thanks, I've changed `unsigned char*` to just `unsigned char`.

Comment: @ChristianStewart Also if you specified what you're using it for, I would likely tell you you're doing it wrong and suggest a better way of doing it, whatever it is :). (In general, it is rarely the case you need to handle memory as a chunk of bytes rather than a type-rich "environment".)

Comment: Well, I've loaded a known data structure (of classes) from another process using ReadProcessMemory into that buffer (unsigned chars as they are size 1 byte right?) and am now re-casting it to the known data structure (a single class). A couple issues I see with this are there are POINTERS in the data, which point to absolutely nothing within MY process, so I have to resolve those when called..

Comment: @ChristianStewart ah, right, then such buffers aren't a terrible idea, and yeah, unsigned char will be 1 byte, however-many bits that may be in arcane corners of the universe

Comment: Yeah, now the problem is, all of the pointers point to things in ANOTHER PROCESS, so I have to go through all of them and load them int o the local process.. oh lord..

Comment: @ChristianStewart Doesn't windows API provide a reasonable marshaller-concept sort of thing?

Comment: I have no idea if they give you something that can literally copy an entire class (given its memory range within another process `HANDLE`) into a local pointer within the local process. If so, that would make my day (and night)...